# od -c (directory) to get file names and inodes

Tags: linux, bash, directory-structure

Years ago I use to do:
`$ od -c .`

to get a dump of the current directory and show the inodes.
This no longer works ... anyone know: why or what I can do?

I was just demonstrating the 'beauty' of everything is a file to someone.

Craig

Answer (score 0):

`od` internally calls `open()` and then `read()`; from `man 2 read`, **errors** section

> `EISDIR` fd refers to a directory.

That is, you cannot read bytes from a directory. Maybe in some old version of Linux or in some other *nix system it was allowed, but not in today Linux.

Comment: That was pre-Linux actually (SVR2 for instance, possibly SVr3).  In the 1980s, directory files were a fixed number characters per entry -- 2 for inode and 14 for the filename.  The opendir, etc., functions were introduced to hide the details of accessing longer names.